# How to Create a Speedometer like Control

Tags: windows-phone-8

Id like to play around with a graphing option that looks like a speedometer. I have seen these in some apps, typically when measuring network speed, mph, etc. Is there some sort of control I can include or reference in my project to use? If not, how might I go about creating something like this? It seems like it would be an excellent graphing tool but I have not come across any resources that show how to do something like this in WP8.